# Python Numpy installation sanity check error

Tags: python, numpy

I was trying to run a block of python codes but I got this error. I installed all the necessary packages.

*RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation ('D:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\**init**.py') fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime. See this issue for more information: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1207405/fmod-after-an-update-to-windows-2004-is-causing-a.html*

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: Did you read what the error message linked to?

Comment: You're the second one to ask this question today, can you give us more details about your windows system

Comment: I am literally running latest version of windows and getting this. Version 20H2

Comment: @mkrieger1 the link is to a weird Microsoft forum but it does not relate to this issue whatsoever.

Comment: @Al-BaraaEl-Hag I am using Windows 10 and Python 3.8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This did the job:

pip install numpy==1.19.3

I can see it's a new error I also had it a couple of minutes ago when I just installed numpy and tensorflow through console.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/1241964/view.html

Here the link, the link given actually worked. :)